# Inquiry about pwm sensor

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, sensor, pwm

This is the electronic circuit of pulse width modulation sensor , i want to know how this circuit works in details.
[image]

Comment: Please read the rules, this question is too broad. EE.SE doesn't answer broad questions. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask We do like specific questions. Do research, learn the circuit. When you get stuck ask a question

Comment: Your question is a bit cheeky and also badly written. Please use proper punctuation and capitalisation for legibility. In any case there isn't enough detail in the schematic to figure out how it works. The oscillator and amplifier are block diagrams and don't give a clue as to the innards.

Answer (score 2):

The basics, as much as can be gleamed from the schematic (partly a guess):

- The oscillator probably spits out a [sawtooth wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave) at the pulse width modulation frequency.
- The sensor creates a voltage proportional to something that is sensed.
- The triangle thing seems to be a [comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator), when the sawtooth wave voltage is less than the sensor voltage, it spits out 0V, when the sawtooth wave voltage is greater than the sensor voltage, it spits out 10V (from the power supply).  It is also possible that the opposite happens (0V when the sawtooth wave voltage is greater than the sensor voltage)
- The transistor is in a [common emitter configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_emitter).  It isn't really clear to me why this is here:  the comparator should output the same voltage, and the common emitter amplifier with emitter degeneration (the resistor on the bottom) doesn't work very well as a buffer.

This should be more than enough for you to start learning about this circuit and come back with a good question for us to answer.